# How to get google cloud project number programmaticaly?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I want to use Google Secret Manager in my project. To access a saved secret it is necessary to provide a secret name which contains Google project number. It will be convinient to get this number proramatically to form secret name and no to save it in the enviroment variable. I use node.js runtime for my project. I know there is a library google-auth-library which allow to get project id. Is it possible to get project number somehow?

Answer (score 4):

You can access secrets by `project_id` or `project_number`. The following are *both* valid resource IDs that point to the same secret:

```
projects/my-project/secrets/my-secret
```

```
projects/1234567890/secrets/my-secret
```

---

You can get metadata, including `project_id` and `project_number` from the [metadata service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata). There are many [default values](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/default-metadata-values). The ones you're looking for are `numeric-project-id` and `project-id`.

Here is an example using `curl` to access the metadata service. You would run this **inside your workload**, typically during initial boot:

```sh
curl "https://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" \
  --header "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

Note: the `Metadata-Flavor: Google` header is required.

To access these values from Node, you can construct your own http client. Alternatively, you can use the [googleapis/gcp-metadata](https://github.com/googleapis/gcp-metadata) package:

```js
const gcpMetadata = require('gcp-metadata');

async function projectID() {
  const id = await gcpMetadata.project('project-id');
  return id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send a GET request to the [Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/get)

`https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID?alt=json`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following method can be useful in your case, but I put it here, just in case:

`gcloud projects list --filter="$PROJECT_ID" --format="value(PROJECT_NUMBER)"`

it should return the project number based on the project identifier (in the `PROJECT_ID` variable), under assumption, that a user (or a service account) who/which runs that command has relevant permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this from outside a Cloud VM, so that the metadata service is not available, you can use the Resource Manager API to convert the project name to project number:

```js
const {ProjectsClient} = require('@google-cloud/resource-manager').v3;
const resourcemanagerClient = new ProjectsClient();

let projectId = 'your-project-id-123'; // TODO: replace with your project ID
const [response] = await resourcemanagerClient.getProject({name: projectId});
let projectNumber = response.name.split('/')[1];
```